# How to include repeatable descriptions based on a product tag with Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have groups of same products, for example, t-shirts and longsleeve. I want to attach below product description three tabs with information that is model-dependent, so repeatable in every t-shirt. I wonder if there is better practice to do that, instead using "case"? In fact, I would have around 15 tags and prefer to avoid the mess in the code.

```
<!--Start tab labels-->
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a class="active" href="#tab1">Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Care</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Details</a></li>
</ul>
<!--Start tab content-->
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li class="active" id="tab1">
    {% case product_tag %}
    {% when 't-shirt' %}
        Our bestselling men's T shirt — in your pick of classic colors at a great price for stocking up.
    {% when 'longsleeve' %}
        Classic Long-Sleeve Cotton Tee features the same great fit with iconic Champion graphics. 
    {% endcase %}
  </li>
  <li id="tab2">
    {% case product_tag %}
    {% when 't-shirt' %}
        Wash up to 40 C.
    {% when 'longsleeve' %}
        Wash in cold water and do not iron!
    {% endcase %}
  </li>
  <li id="tab3">
    {% case product_tag %}
    {% when 't-shirt' %}
        100% cotton jersey feels great, won't weigh you down. (Grey and 
Heather are cotton-rich blends.)
Set-in mini-ribbed crewneck keeps its shape wash after wash.
Shoulder-to-shoulder taping helps prevent stretch-out and rip-out.
Durable double stitching reinforces cuffs and hem.
    {% when 'longsleeve' %}
        ll cotton comfort and breathability (Greys are a cotton-rich blend).
Ribbed cuffs and collar keep you covered.
Dyed-to-match back neck tape for no-itch comfort.
Bottom hem with clean-finish single needle stitching.
Iconic C logo on sleeve.
    {% endcase %}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use metafields for this. Metafields are custom fields that can be attached to Shopify objects and then [referenced in Liquid.](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield) They can be uploaded [using the Shopify API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/metafield), an [app from the App Store](https://apps.shopify.com/search/query?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=metafields), or [using the Shopify bulk editor.](https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/53573123-secrets-of-the-shopify-bulk-editor)

Using product metafields would look like this:

```html
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li class="active" id="tab1">
     {{ product.metafields.private.extra_info }}
  </li>
  <li id="tab2">
    {{ product.metafields.private.washing_instructions }}
  </li>
  <li id="tab3">
    {{ product.metafields.private.further_info }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Josh! Thank you for an answer! I think my example wasn't clear enough so I updated it! that "t-shirt info", "...care instructions" were only placeholders that had to symbolize various texts that are model dependent! I hope it's now easier to understand :) Thanks!

Comment: I see, you might try using metafields then. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep code clearer, you can store those information in pages, and then call the content of that page, depending on its tags, for example

```
{{pages[product.tags.first].content}}
```